# City/Country - Post/Zip code matching/validation checking on web pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I'm currently looking for possible ways to implement a post code/zip code checking mechanism on my "contact us" web page where the user selects a country and/or city and the system lists or validates the associated post/zip codes against the available and valid post codes in that region preferably through JavaScript or jQuery.

Comment: Submit some piece of code.

Comment: I have thought about running a regular expression type check on the codes associated to each country but finding this out manually is a pain since each country has a different post code format and there are literally over 150 of them out there.  Have tried to look for some APIs out there that might be doing that, however, didn't find anything useful yet, hence posting a question here. I'm still searching out there for some possible solutions to this.

Comment: I'm asking if there is a technique to do this in either of the front-end scripting languages/libraries.  The code is easy to imagine, a form that contains a country drop down list followed by a city and post code, where the post code needs to be checked against the country chosen.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in JavaScript or jQuery with AJAX and a few MySQL queries, there are several free zipcode databases you can use... I wouldn't suggest trying to implement this as a standalone JavaScript or jQuery script...

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be to validate the posdtcode using an addressing API (such as Postcode Anywhere's, the company I work for: http://www.postcodeanywhere.co.uk/support/webservices/PostcodeAnywhereInternational/Interactive/RetrieveByPostalCode/v2.2/default.aspx) to check for the presence of a Postcode as well as validating it's format. THis can be done easily via JavaScript. It would also allow you to validate that the city matches.